# swift in UI test(test the num of cells in UITable View)

Tags: ios, swift, uitest

I am very new to UI test. I have an `UITableView` in my storyboard and it contains some cells. 
Update:
I want to assert that the num of cells in `UITableView` when the app launches will be more than 0. But I don't know how to code this part.Using `NSPredicate`? Or others?

```
 func testCellsNum()
{
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        let tableCell = app.tableRows.count
    //Then what should I do ?
        XCTAssertGreaterThan(tableCell, 0, "should greater than 0")//this line doesn't work


}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you only have one table:

```
func testExample() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let tablesQuery = app.tables
    let count = tablesQuery.cells.count
    XCTAssert(count > 0)
}
```

If you have multi tables,using this to get first or any index you want

```
 tablesQuery.elementAtIndex(0).cells
```

Comment: I have two scenes. The first one has UITableView. When I click the first cell in it, it will enter the second scene. There is ImageCells on the second scene. How could I test the num of images cells in the second scene?

Comment: See the the post I answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33643956/3940672,you can use recoding to generate original code,then make a little changes with the code I post

Comment: You could also add an **accessibilityIdentifier** to your tableview like `myTableView.accessibilityIdentifier = “myUniqueTableViewIdentifier”`, once done, you can access the tableView in your test case like: `let myTableView = app.tables.matching(identifier: "myUniqueTableViewIdentifier")`

Comment: Can anyone confirm this works in iOS 11, Xcode 9? The assert always fails for me, even with static cells.

Comment: @damjandd I'm running into the same issue, might be related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679817/wrong-cells-count-for-collection-view-in-ui-tests