# how to write UI test to test whether image existing when click the first cell in an UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitest

There is an `UITableView` in my storyboard. It contains 5 Table view cells.
When I click the first cell, it will go to the second UIView and show the corresponding images. How could I code the UITest part to test whether the image show up when I click the first cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a magic part of XCode 7- **UIRecording**

First selected the testCase,and start recording like the Gif[image]

Then you will see,UIRecording create UITest code for you,In my case,I get

```
  let app = XCUIApplication()
  app.tables/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.staticTexts["Hello"]/*[[".cells.staticTexts[\"Hello\"]",".staticTexts[\"Hello\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/.tap()
  app.otherElements.containingType(.NavigationBar, identifier:"UIView").childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Image).element.tap()
```

Then,I just need a little change

```
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.tables.cells.elementBoundByIndex(0).tap()
    let imageView =  app.otherElements.containingType(.NavigationBar, identifier:"UIView").childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Image)
    let count = imageView.images.count
    XCTAssert(count != 0)
```

So,the there are mainly two step

- Let UIRecording Create codes for you
- Make a little changes,such as add Assert,query by index,and so on.

Then run